# I'm having ROS kinetic is there anyway to install ROS-Industrial package on the kinetic or I should install ROS Hydro/Indigo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install the ROS-Industrial package on my Kinetic as I'm working with ABB IRB14000 Robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273272/i%27m-having-ros-kinetic-is-there-anyway-to-install-ros-industrial-package-on-the-kinetic-or-i-should-install-ros-hydro/indigo?/) by [Ahmad](https://answers.ros.org/users/32189/ahmad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q254327.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0